# Problema al limitar el numero de inserciones de un mismo id a N veces

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo la siguiente tabla :

```
CREATE TABLE vehiculos_conductores(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    id_conductor INT NOT NULL,
    id_vehiculo INT NOT NULL,


    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_conductor) REFERENCES conductores.id,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_vehiculo) REFERENCES vehiculos.id


);
```

Quisiera obviar las tablas a las que hace **referencia** (`conductores` y `vehiculos` ) para enfocarnos  en lo importante: 

El limites de veces que un conductor puede ser insertado en esta tabla (*imaginemos **3 veces***).

**¿Como podria crear esa limitacion de *3 veces* en la tabla?** Claro que si ya esta registrado 3 veces el mismo conductor en diferente coche, y se **da de baja en uno** tenga la posibilidad de ser insertado una vez mas (**hasta llegar a 3 como maximo**)

Comment: Estas son reglas de negocios. Aunque podrias controlar esto con un trigger que cancele la insercion antes de hacerla, creo que lo mejor es que plantees esto en la aplicacion que maneja el negocio. poner esta clase de reglas en la base de datos, a veces la hace confusa. Pero se puede. Eso es lo que buscas?

Comment: Bueno, realmente habia pensado tambien hacer un `count` que si fuese menor que **X** que insertara pero pense que era menos optimo

Comment: Todo depende de tu sistema y de como sea tu arquitectura. Podria hacerse de varias formas (que se ingrese por un store procedure, controlado por un trigger, que lo controle tu sistema en una transaccion). No hay una sola forma, pero lo importante es que todas tus reglas de negocios esten en un solo lugar.

Comment: Y me podrias decir una para ir probando que no sea muy compleja pero cumpla su funcion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien te indica @gbianchi, éste sería el posible disparador:

```
CREATE TRIGGER conductores BEFORE INSERT
  ON vehiculos_conductores FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF(
        SELECT COUNT(*)>=3 FROM vehiculos_conductores
          WHERE id_conductor=NEW.id_conductor
      ) THEN SET new.id_conductor=NULL;
      END IF;
  END;
```

Una vez que en tu tabla insertes estos datos:

```
INSERT INTO vehiculos_conductores (id_conductor, id_vehiculo) VALUES
  (1,1),
  (1,2),
  (1,3),
  (2,1);
```

Debería darte un error al insertar éste último:

```
INSERT INTO vehiculos_conductores (id_conductor, id_vehiculo) VALUES
  (1,4);
```

Reconozco que, forzar el error de insertar un NULL cuando haya más de 3 registros, tiene margen de mejora pero, para ilustrar la idea, espero que me lo permitáis :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte tan bueno. Seria buena practica tratarlo desde el un **controlador**  que haga en mi proyecto ?

Comment: Entiendo que por controlador te refieres a la parte de negocio de tu MVC. Coincido con @gbianchi en que, mientras tengas todas las reglas de negocio junta, donde prefieras... Hay quien prefiere limpia la base de datos y quien prefiere limpio el código... :) Supongo que cada cual las colocará donde menos esfuerzo le suponga programarlas...

Comment: [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)